# Trouble getting into grub menu on fresh ubuntu server install

Tags: boot, server, grub2, mac

I have already set up one old computer and I'm trying to set up my 2010 old mac desktop to a server.
When I select my boot drive from the usb it shows commands for about 2 seconds then goes black. I can not even get to the select language screen it goes black almost right away. I have tried to get into grub using right shift and escape but the screen just shows one cursor.

i do not know if this helps but this computer previously I put ubuntu on and cold only install it using safe graphics then when I removed the usb and rebooted I got a black screen again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the exact make and model with specs like processor etc.? This may help people answer the question.